# error MSB6006: "java" exited with code 2 on Xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know this question has been asked several times- My Xamarin Android package builds just fine, and gives me this error- I can't run ANY project (including fresh new projects) on any emulator or my own physical Android- Runs totally fine on IOS. I'm on Mac

I've tried everything I could find online

- Reinstalling VS 2019
- Using VS 2022
- Reinstalling Xamarin and all emulators as well as Java SDKs and Android SDKs
- Enabling/disabling multidex or Appkey signing with debug.keystore and other custom made keys ( this gives error MSB6006: "java" exited with code 1.) on both debug and release

Sometimes with different parameters, I get "error ADB0010 The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES)."

Also not able to find a solution for that

This problem came about after updating an app on google play console, but I don't see why this would have anything to do with it

If anybody could help, it'd be greatly appreciated- I'm completely unable to test my xamarin projects on Android at all and it's driving me crazy.

Edit:
The code that is supposedly the culprit is:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2309,2)

Which is

```
<AndroidApkSigner Condition=" '$(AndroidUseApkSigner)' == 'true' "
    ApkSignerJar="$(ApkSignerJar)"
    ApkToSign="%(ApkAbiFilesAligned.Identity)"
    KeyStore="$(_ApkKeyStore)"
    KeyAlias="$(_ApkKeyAlias)"
    KeyPass="$(_ApkKeyPass)"
    StorePass="$(_ApkStorePass)"
    PlatformKey="$(AndroidSigningPlatformKey)"
    PlatformCert="$(AndroidSigningPlatformCert)"
    ToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
    ToolExe="$(JavaToolExe)"
    ManifestFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
    AdditionalArguments="$(AndroidApkSignerAdditionalArguments)"
/>
```

Edit 2:

When ASB00100 shows up here's the error log:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES).
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x000de] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:338
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass100_0.b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:803  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in :0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001cf] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:206
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0042f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:223
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x001c0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:338
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x0032d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:355
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.RunTaskAsync () [0x002fb] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:212

culprit (Common.Debugging.Targets):

```
    <FastDeploy
  Condition=" '$(AndroidPackageFormat)' != 'aab' "
  AdbTarget="$(AdbTarget)"
  AllowDeltaInstall="$(_AndroidAllowDeltaInstall)"
  DiagnosticLogging="$(_FastDeploymentDiagnosticLogging)"
  FastDevFiles="@(_FilteredFastDevFiles);@(_ResolvedSymbols);@(_ResolvedConfigFiles)"
  FastDevToolPath="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\lib"
  EmbedAssembliesIntoApk="$(EmbedAssembliesIntoApk)"
  PrimaryCpuAbi="$(_PrimaryCpuAbi)"
  PreserveUserData="$(AndroidPreserveUserData)"
  PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
  PackageFile="$(_ApkToInstall)"
  ReInstall="$(_ReInstall)"
  ToolVersion="$(AndroidFastDeploymentToolVersion)"
  UploadFlagFile="$(_UploadFlag)"
  UsingAndroidNETSdk="$(UsingAndroidNETSdk)"
  UserID="$(AndroidDeviceUserId)"
/>
```

Comment: You have tried all the suggestions I could find online.  I was not able to reproduce this issue. It would be better to post in Issue of GitHub to get further help. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues